How to print logs to serial port without specifying 'console' in Linux?
I am working on an embedded Linux system (5.19.10), and I am using busybox as the main part of file system.
Now I am trying to run a test which should output logs to the serial port (ttyS0). But I did NOT configure console in the kernel command line.
The /etc/inittab is as follows,
# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Put a getty on the serial port
#::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS1 115200 vt100
#no login
::respawn:-/bin/sh

# Stuff to do for the 3-finger salute
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot

# Stuff to do before rebooting
null::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK
null::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
null::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a

I changed the /etc/profile as follows,
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 speed 38400
setconsole /dev/ttyS0
echo "Hello world" > /dev/ttyS0
/home/test/test_app 2>&1 &

When system booted up, I can see Hello world in the serial port. But I cannot see the shell prompt or the logs from the test_app.
I think the system console is NOT being configured correctly in this case.
So, I am wondering is there any gentle way to set the system console in my own script (e.g. /etc/init.d/rcS or /etc/profile) without using getty or console=XXX and make the log output to the serial expected console??

echo "Hello world" > /dev/ttyS0

That > /dev/ttyS0 the important part here. You explicitly instruct your shell to redirect output of your echo command to the serial port.
If you want your test_app to do the same, you'd have to test_app > /dev/ttyS0, also. setconsole does something different!

Ah，I got your test_app > /dev/ttyS0, good idea. But what does setconsole do? Its name looks pretty match to what I want to do, but it does NOT.

it tells the kernel to redirect its error console output (if enabled at all) to a different device

Other than explicitly redirecting to /dev/ttyS0, is there any other way to set system console in user space??

what do you exactly mean with "system console"? Because what > /dev/ttyS0 does is literally take /dev/ttyS0, open it, and launch the program specified it with that being its standard output. That's exactly what you need.

test_app > /dev/ttyS0 can make the test_app to output its own logs to the serial port, but what about other executives? I am wondering if there is a way to change the default console in the system wide. Using > /dev/ttyS0 for many executives I really care about is very time-consuming.

no, there isn't. Because that simply doesn't exist: any process writes to the standard output that it has been passed at creation; so you need to modify which standard output is passed at creation time. You can do so using > /dev/ttyS0.

I got you. Thanks for answering. I voted for your answer already.
